# How to show $\epsilon > \frac{3^n -1}{n! + 124} > \frac{1}{n!}$

Tags: number-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I'm having some problems with proving infimum of some set. I got stuck where I need to show the following:

$$ \forall_{\epsilon > 0}\ \exists_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\ \epsilon > \frac{3^n -1}{n! + 124} $$

So obviously $\epsilon > \frac{3^n -1}{n! + 124}  > \frac{1}{n!} $ (I guess for $n \geq 5 $)

But how to move it from this point?

**EDIT:**

So following your hints:

$n! + 124 =  1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdots n  + 124 > 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdots 4= 6\cdot 4^{n-3}$

$\epsilon > \frac{3^n}{4^{n-3}} > \frac{3^n -1}{6 \cdot 4^{n-3}} > \frac{3^n -1}{n! + 124}$

So I have $\frac{\epsilon}{64} > (\frac{3}{4})^n$

So $ \log_{}{\frac{\epsilon}{64} > n \cdot \log{}{\frac{3}{4}}}$

So $n > \log_{\frac{3}{4}}{\frac{\epsilon}{64}}$

So there exists $ n = floor(\log_{\frac{3}{4}}{\frac{\epsilon}{64}}) + 1$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important point of confusion and that has to be corrected is that you *don't* want to show that
$$
\varepsilon > \frac{3^n-1}{n!+124}>\frac{1}{n!},
$$
since that would not show your statement. It goes in the wrong direction in some sense.

Rather, you should try to find some convincing $f(n)$ such that
$$
\varepsilon > f(n) > \frac{3^n-1}{n!+124}
$$
for large $n$, and such that $f(n)$ is decreasing to zero as $n\to+\infty$.

I think @5xum gives you a nice way to do this with
$$
f(n)=\frac{3^n-1}{6\cdot 4^{n-3}}.
$$

Comment: So I can prove $\epsilon > \frac{3^n -1}{n! + 124}$ by finding $f(X)$ that goes between this inequality? I though It must be sth like $\frac{3^n -1}{n! + 124} > f(x)$

Comment: Indeed, you want to have something in between.

Comment: Yep, correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

For $n > 3$, you can use the fact that
$$n! + 124 =  1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdot 4\cdots n  + 124 > 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdots 4> 6\cdot 4^{n-3} $$

Also, use the fact that if $a>b>0$, then $0<\frac 1a < \frac1b$

Comment: (↑) If you keep the $124$ another step, then I think you can omit the $n>3$. Not that it really matters... Btw, as it is written now the last $>$ is meant to be an $=$, right?